# Localising asp.net app to HK with language set to english

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, cultureinfo

I am building a multilingual web app. The client requires the site for HK to be displayed in English. Unfortunately, "en-HK" is not a valid culture in asp.net, so I tried to get around it using "zh-hk". However, this caused the date time strings (with format of dd-MMM-yyyy) to be displayed in Chinese.

Is there any way to display the language in english but localise it to Hk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CurrentUICulture` controls selection of localized resources: set it to an English culture (e.g. "en" or "en-GB").

`CurrentCulture` controls number and date formats etc., including day and month names.  Either set it to "en-GB", or set it to a custom culture based on "en-GB", but with any modifications you want (e.g. your post suggests you want "-" as date separator: dd-MMM-yyyy).

Neither of these affects time zone etc, so I don't really see why it would be a problem simply to use "en-GB".

Comment: what if I need to display the date in en-GB format, but the currency localised to Malaysian ringgit?

Comment: You could create a custom culture with a custom NumberFormatInfo that has the appropriate CurrencySymbol etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Hong Kong but given its recent history, the English language conventions used there are probably based on UK English rather than US English. The short date format used in Hong Kong (documented on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)) certainly appears to support this assertion: it's day/month/year (British style, unlike the US style where it's month/day/year).

You could always create a custom culture (supported by Windows 7 onwards) for en-HK. This is done by using the [CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx) class and will allow you to create your en-HK CultureInfo, based on the en-GB culture if my comment above is correct. This would allow you to customize some of the elements of the CultureInfo if you wish to (and more importantly, if you know what is different in Hong Kong). By basing your custom culture on en-GB, your date formats will show month names in English. But creating a custom culture is probably overkill.

More simply, you could use the en-GB Culture name. Your app probably doesn't use some of the more arcane things in the en-GB culture that wouldn't apply to Hong Kong.

**Note:** In case there is any confusion, for date formatting `Thread.CurrentUICulture` has no effect whatsoever--it's entirely dependent on what `Thread.CurrentCulture` is set to (and which must be a specific culture, unlike CurrentUICulture for which a neutral culture such as "en" is OK).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't combine your culture strings yourself (meaning, en-HK is not valid unless it is listed in .NET).

However, they have two different culture settings per thread:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

Which both controls different things. Maybe that can let you use english as language but HK as localized formats.

You could also override the formatting of dates and such specifically, and maybe find better cultureinfos that will give you the date format that you need.